# Rails 3: Access polymorphic_url method in separate module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, module

I know I can call `url_helpers` in a separate module `lib/utils.rb` like this

```
module Utils
  def self.get_url(object=nil)
    if object.nil?
      return Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.root_url
    else
      return Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.polymorphic_url(object)
    end
  end
end
```

How can I access `polymorphic_url`? With this code, I get:

```
undefined method `polymorphic_url' for #<Module:0x00000004be0128>
```

I'm using Rails 3.2.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consult with APIdocks on such matters. Depending on Rails version, you can find `polymorphic_url` in a couple of different places:

1. [Rails 4](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_url).
2. [Rails 3](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_url).

For Rails 4, all you need to do is to include appropriate module to your module/class:

```
include ActionController::PolymorphicRoutes
```

That's it!

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I forgot to mention I'm on Rails 3. I did what you suggest, but with this `ActionDispatch::Routing::PolymorphicRoutes.polymorphic_url(object)` I get this error: `undefined method 'polymorphic_url' for ActionDispatch::Routing::PolymorphicRoutes:Module`, so I thought the class hierarchy did not match the method path or someting...

Comment: Well, that's pretty strange. In Rails v 3.2.16 it is defined in that module: `ActionDispatch::Routing::PolymorphicRoutes`. What exact version of Rails do you use?

Comment: Have you tried to include that module instead of calling its methods?

Comment: The problem is that these methods defined as instance methods. `polymorphic_url` can't be called on module itself, but can be called on instance of the class (which has `PolymorphicRoutes` included).

Comment: Ok, so it won't work for me as I have class method? (I updated the example)